# What is the best connection model multiple parallel requests in iOS

Tags: ios, multithreading, asynchronous, nsurlconnection, synchronous

I have a search application which displays result from server. The search request fires with every key presses ( i.e search as i type). There will be 5 requests for every search (say the results are put into UITableView with 5 sections and the rows of each section has content fed from separate connections) . I want to know the best connection model / architecture for this case.

First, I tried asynchronous NSUrlConnection method in the single thread. But, since there will be processing of the result from a connection , single threaded model was time consuming.

Then, I tried synchronous method in multiple parallel threads , but canceling a synchronous thread is not possible. Then, I tried asynchronous connections in multiple threads.

My query is which is the best connection model / architecture for this case. 
Thanks.